# How do I access a stored procedure on a different database on the same server

Tags: sql-server

Here is my code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [admin].[UpdateMiddleSchoolTranscriptsGPA_weight]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --EXEC webapp.sa.[MMSD].[UpdateMiddleSchoolTranscriptsGPA_weight]

    EXEC MMSD.UpdateMiddleSchoolTranscriptsGPA_weight

END
```

Im using alter because i already made the existing procedure, i named it admin because i need to call the one from the mmsd database also i need to access it using some php button I wrote. any  help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can address objects in other databases by using three part naming.

Database.Schema.Object

Four part naming adds the ServerName to the start.

Comment: The only need to use a four-part naming convention would be if the stored procedure is on a different instance.  In which case, you would also need to create a Linked Server to the target instance.  However, for the purpose of the question posed, it seems like the database lives within the same instances as the calling stored procedure.

Comment: I know, I was just trying to clarify for the OP.  The comment in their code uses four part naming.